# iOS custom TableViewCell row height (nested FlowLayout)

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'm trying to put the Flowlayout into TableViewCell content. 
[image] [image]

Everything works fine, but I want to setup dynamic row height based on FlowLayout height. 
Using the next method we can get need size. But when I setting it to value that is not equal "44" - FlowLayout stops to show its content. It works only with 44 px.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 44.0;
}
```

[image];

Changing row height via storyboard produces the same result. So Is it possible to contorl the size of nested FlowLayout?

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on cimgf.com Please see: http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/

Comment: Is this article shows why the content of nested collection disappeared after row height is changed. I can easily calculate need height and change the row height, but then content of nested layout disappear.